# Hammer.js Vertical Swipes Are Erratic

Tags: hammer.js

It seems that 'swipeup' and 'swipedown' events are not fired consistently. Is this a known issue?

I'm testing this pen on OSX/Chrome with a mouse: http://codepen.io/felixturner/pen/RWbPoN

```
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

//enable all directions
mc.get('swipe').set({
  direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL
});

// listen to events...
mc.on("swipeup swipedown swipeleft swiperight tap press", function(ev) {
  myElement.textContent = ev.type + " gesture detected.";
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the threshold and velocity fixed this issue:

```
mc.get('swipe').set({
  direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL,
  threshold: 1, 
  velocity:0.1
});
```